# Как сделать скроллинг для блоков не выходил за рамки границы?

Tags: css

У меня есть комнаты с классом chat-list_rooms и список сообщений с классом chat-message. Мне нужно, чтобы при превышение body. Пока не понял как. Потому что body сам по себе резиновый и если сделать его hidden то скроллы не будут работать так как нужно, то есть скролла не будет и форма отправки сообщение тоже исчезник в пределах скрытой области.

```css
/* Mixins */


/* Style */

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  outline: none;
}

i {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chat-index {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0px 15%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left {
  border-right: none;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-profile {
  background: #dc3545;
  color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-row: 20px 1fr;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-profile_content {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-profile_content .avatar-user {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-profile_content .avatar-user img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-profile_content .user-fullname {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_search {
  position: relative;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_search .search-icon {
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #a2a2a2;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_search input {
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_search .close-icon {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #a2a2a2;
  display: none;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_rooms {
  overflow: auto;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_content {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 65px 1fr;
  padding: 10px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_content .avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_content .avatar img {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_content_description_body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_content_description_body_message {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 5fr 50px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5fr 1fr;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #dc3545;
  color: #fff;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info_user_fullname {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info_user_last_visit {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info_search {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info_search_icon {
  text-align: right;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info_search_icon i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-message {
  border-left: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  overflow: auto;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-message_content {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-message_content.interlocutor-message {
  float: left;
  background: #d8d8d8;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-message_content.own-message {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-message_content_date {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #847979;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  align-items: center;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 4fr 0.1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_attach {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_attach:hover {
  color: #dc3545;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_message {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_message textarea {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  resize: none;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_submit button {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_submit button:hover {
  color: #dc3545;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="chat-index">
  <div class="chat-column-left">
    <div class="chat-profile">
      <i class="material-icons">dehaze</i>
      <div class="chat-profile_content">
        <div class="avatar-user">
          <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="user-fullname">Петров Петр</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-list">
      <div class="chat-list_search">
        <i class="material-icons search-icon">search</i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск" id="search">
        <i class="material-icons close-icon">close</i>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-list_rooms">
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-column-right">
    <div class="chat-info">
      <div class="chat-info_user">
        <div class="chat-info_user_fullname">Иван Иванов</div>
        <div class="chat-info_user_last_visit">Был в сети 34 минут</div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-info_search">
        <div class="chat-info_search_icon">
          <label for="search">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-message">
      <div class="chat-message_content interlocutor-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content interlocutor-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content interlocutor-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content own-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content own-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content interlocutor-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content interlocutor-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content own-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-form">
      <form action="#" class="chat-form_form">
        <div class="chat-form_form_attach">
          <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-form_form_message">
          <textarea placeholder="Введите текст"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-form_form_submit">
          <button>
            <i class="material-icons">send</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот песочница
https://codepen.io/rusline/pen/dwPaGQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал фиксированным высоте через vh. То выходит так как надо

Убрал из .chat-column-right `display:grid`
И зафиксировал высоту список комнат 
`&_rooms {
        overflow: auto;
        height: 55vh
      }`

```css
/* Mixins */


/* Style */

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input:focus {
  border: 1px solid 1px;
  outline: none;
}

i {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.chat-index {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0px 15%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left {
  border-right: none;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-profile {
  background: #dc3545;
  color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-row: 20px 1fr;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-profile_content {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-profile_content .avatar-user {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-profile_content .avatar-user img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-profile_content .user-fullname {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_search {
  position: relative;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_search .search-icon {
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #a2a2a2;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_search input {
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_search .close-icon {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #a2a2a2;
  display: none;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_rooms {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 55vh;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_content {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 65px 1fr;
  padding: 10px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_content .avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_content .avatar img {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_content_description_body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-left .chat-list_content_description_body_message {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5fr 1fr;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #dc3545;
  color: #fff;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info_user_fullname {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info_user_last_visit {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info_search {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info_search_icon {
  text-align: right;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-info_search_icon i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-message {
  border-left: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 80vh;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-message_content {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-message_content.interlocutor-message {
  float: left;
  background: #d8d8d8;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-message_content.own-message {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-message_content_date {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #847979;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  align-items: center;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 4fr 0.1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_attach {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_attach:hover {
  color: #dc3545;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_message {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_message textarea {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  resize: none;
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_submit button {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.chat-index .chat-column-right .chat-form_form_submit button:hover {
  color: #dc3545;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="chat-index">
  <div class="chat-column-left">
    <div class="chat-profile">
      <i class="material-icons">dehaze</i>
      <div class="chat-profile_content">
        <div class="avatar-user">
          <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="user-fullname">Петров Петр</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-list">
      <div class="chat-list_search">
        <i class="material-icons search-icon">search</i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск" id="search">
        <i class="material-icons close-icon">close</i>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-list_rooms">
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-list_content">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--dMTJCIXu--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/myblkoukcgxb3dn1vyd7.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="chat-list_content_description">
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_header">
              <span>Иван Иванов</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-list_content_description_body">
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_message"> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="chat-list_content_description_body_time"> <span>10.12.2019</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-column-right">
    <div class="chat-info">
      <div class="chat-info_user">
        <div class="chat-info_user_fullname">Иван Иванов</div>
        <div class="chat-info_user_last_visit">Был в сети 34 минут</div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-info_search">
        <div class="chat-info_search_icon">
          <label for="search">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-message">
      <div class="chat-message_content interlocutor-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content interlocutor-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content interlocutor-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content own-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content own-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content interlocutor-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content interlocutor-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-message_content own-message">
        <div class="chat-message_content_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id unde laboriosam facilis esse a rem pariatur sequi doloribus corporis doloremque?</div>
        <div class="chat-message_content_date">
          10.12.2019
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-form">
      <form action="#" class="chat-form_form">
        <div class="chat-form_form_attach">
          <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-form_form_message">
          <textarea placeholder="Введите текст"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-form_form_submit">
          <button>
            <i class="material-icons">send</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас не очень понятно записан вопрос и код на препроцессоре читать неудобно. Упростите вопрос, плиз. Тогда можно будет упростить ответ :)

Но похоже что вам надо сделать так, чтобы чат был высотой во весь экран, а скроллирование происходило внутри чата. Ну как чат во вконтакте, например. Да? Я вижу два подхода к тому как это можно сделать.

1) Начиная от элемента html и вглубь до самого окна с лентой диалога вы повсеместно используете **height: 100%;** и там где начинается лента сообщений используете **overflow-y: scroll**. Таким образом вы создадите скролл в нужном месте, а главный страничный скролл выключится.

2) Более предпочтительно -- это оставить ленту сообщений как основной контент страницы и тогда эта лента будет скроллироваться как обычно. Все остальные элементы интерфейса чата, в таком случае, делаете через **position: fixed**. Такие элементы не будут поддаваться скроллу.